# Android Joda Time - How to Load UTC from File

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, utc

I am using Joda Time. I want to compare 2 dates/times A and B to determine if B has exceeded A.

Problem - When I logcat A it's not in UTC. When I logcat B it's in UTC. Therefore the comparison is not real.

```
A - A UTC time loaded from a file
B -The "System Time" in UTC
```

Code:

```
A - DateTime csvTime = new DateTime( inArray[5] ) ; //inArray[x] is loaded from a file and has this format: 2017-02-10T01:09:00Z
B - new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

Question - How do I load inArray[5] so it is truly in UTC and compares with B accurately?

Thanks in advance and yes I have looked at 100s of posts on this. I have yet to find a post that tells me the syntax for A above, how to store an external ISO 8601 format date in UTC internal. I have played around with TimeZone set default to force Joda/JVMP default TZ but that then puts me in a position of having to specify the TimeZone which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is already in UTC (trailing "Z") then I suggest you to parse it this way:

```
DateTime dt =
    ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(
        "2017-02-10T01:09:00Z"
    );
System.out.println(dt); // 2017-02-10T01:09:00.000Z
```

Otherwise you could tranform your A-DateTime to UTC by [withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-).

Comment: Thank you. That (dt) worked beautifully. I appreciate it. Last question...now how do I display dt in the local time / timezone as set by my android ?

Comment: @FrankZappa What about using `withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())`? This would work as long as the user has not adjusted the clock or system zone on his/her device.

Comment: thanks. I will try that. Do you have experience  serializing/deserializing objects with Joda's DateTime field included? I am using gson for serialization. My serialization was working until I changed java date to Joda's DateTime , then deserialization crashed. So I then added google's DateTimeTypeConverter to serialize/deserialize. It no longer crashes on the serialization but upon deserialization it seems the time has changed. Any thoughts?

Comment: @FrankZappa I have no special experiences with serialization of Joda-objects but have heard that some external serializing APIs (not standard Java) have problems in modelling the Java serialization spec. Special converters will usually solve such problems however (as you reported the Google-tool as example). And since you work on Android, Proguard might also be in the way. Anyway, this question is not suitable for the comment-format.

Comment: I took your advice and created another post. I am not convinced this is serialization. Please take a look at the 8 hour difference here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256267/android-joda-time-gson-deserialization#42256267